# How to make CSS grid column width to be "max-content" but not bigger than 50%

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make CSS grid column width to be "max-content" but not bigger than 50%?
So it looks something like this when first column content exceeds 50% width.
[image]
And like this when first column text is short
[image]

I thought something like `minmax(max-content, 1fr)` should work, but seems like `1fr` is never applied for some reason.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid-1 {
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

.grid-2 {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 1fr) 1fr;
}

.grid + .grid {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 16px;
  background: gray;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

.grid-description {
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  background: teal;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="grid grid-1">
    <div class="grid-description">Example 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">User Name</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Siobhan Hill</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Job</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid grid-2">
    <div class="grid-description">Example 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Name</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Siobhan Hill</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Job</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this is to use `minmax` for both of your columns.

`minmax(0, max-content) minmax(50%, 1fr)` will set your first column to its max content width, but never wider than 50%.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, max-content) minmax(50%, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 16px;
  background: lightgray;
  border: solid 1px whitesmoke;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-description {
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  background: turquoise;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-description">Example 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">My Name</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Bob Hill</div>
    <div class="grid-item">My Job</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-description">Example 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">My Name</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Bob Hill</div>
    <div class="grid-item">My Job</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are wanting? If so, all I did was replace the `max-content` inside of `minmax` to be `auto`, so instead of `minmax(max-content, 1fr)` it is `minmax(auto, 1fr)`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid-1 {
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}

.grid-2 {
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr) 1fr;
}

.grid + .grid {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 16px;
  background: gray;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

.grid-description {
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  background: teal;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="grid grid-1">
    <div class="grid-description">Example 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">User Name</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Siobhan Hill</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Job</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid grid-2">
    <div class="grid-description">Example 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Name</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Siobhan Hill</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Job</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Software Developer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But is there any universal way? I have one table. The content for it comes from the backend, and I don’t know whether it will be long or short.